# how Keycloak logout can be done in ASP.NET MVC (.Net Framework 4.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, keycloak, owin, logout

integrated Keycloak with my .Net Framework 4.5 MVC projects. Since there is no direct Keycloak client for .Net, I'm using the "Owin.Security.Keycloak-3" NuGet for this. I can login from keykloack page instead of my application login page. I removed the request data by doing             Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes().Select(Function(x) x.AuthenticationType).ToArray()). But still it automatically goes to the same landing page when application runs.

Am using the server parameters in startup class as

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions With {
                            .AuthenticationType = persistentAuthType
                             })
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(persistentAuthType)
        app.UseKeycloakAuthentication(New KeycloakAuthenticationOptions With {
        .Realm = "MYPROJECT",
        .ClientId = "TEST",
        .KeycloakUrl = "https://keycloak.dev.myserver.com",
        .AuthenticationType = persistentAuthType,
        .SignInAsAuthenticationType = persistentAuthType,
        .AllowUnsignedTokens = False,
        .DisableIssuerSigningKeyValidation = True,
        .DisableIssuerValidation = True,
        .DisableAudienceValidation = True,
        .TokenClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
        .Scope = "openid"
})
```

In the logout action in controller ,

Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes().Select(Function(x) x.AuthenticationType).ToArray())

to remove the token.but still goes to the same landing page of the application without showing the keycloak login page.how we can dispose the token or is there a method to logout from keyklock ?